# change data in highchart on changing selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a dropdown and a highchart. I want to display only the data that is selected from the dropdown. Please help

```
 $("#chartSeries").change(function () {
            var type = this.value;
            if (type !== '0') {
                $(chart.series).each(function () {
                    this.update({
                        type: type
                    }, false);
                });
                chart.redraw();
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sunny168/cd5qj1ny/

Comment: What you already have done to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You code is incomplete. On the jsfiddle you only give one chart.

To get the wanted chart, try that :

```
$("#chartSeries").on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value == 1) {
    // Call Summary chart
  } else if (value == 2) {
    // Call Performance chart
  } else {
    // Show a message asking for selection
  }
```

Comment: I want to use the same chart to display different series based on selection